# SQL data truncation for date value

Tags: sql

I'm having a hard time creating a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE `csat` (
    `csat_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `value` INT,
    `month` DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`csat_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `migrated` (
    `migrated_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` INT,
    `description` INT,
    `month` DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`migrated_id`)
);

INSERT INTO csat
VALUES (1, 1, 2017-06-15);

INSERT INTO migrated
VALUES (1, 2, 2018-06-15);
```

I get the error:
    Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '1996' for column 'month' at row 1

It seems like my date is in the right format:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date.asp

I'm also wondering why I need to specify a value on the csat_id, because I thought SQL would just put that in for me since its the primary key.

Comment: add some proper i/p error sample as I could see 1996 as invalid but theres nowhere in the i/p

Comment: 1996 occurs because sql is interpretting that as 2017 subtract 6 subtract 15. James has provided sufficient input.

Comment: Is it the case that For every database it should have given same 1996 value as error? As the Op din mention db name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said which database server you're using, but generally speaking dates are inputted as strings.

You should try the following inserts;

```
INSERT INTO csat (`csat_id`, `value`, `month`)
VALUES (1, 1, '2017-06-15');

INSERT INTO migrated (`migrated_id`, `title`, `description`, `month`)
VALUES (1, 2, 2, '2018-06-15');
```

Also, you should specify which columns you're inserting into. This prevents data from being entered into the wrong fields, especially when schema changes occur.

SQL does auto increment primary key fields (if defined that way). However, you had to define it in your insert statements because you didn't specify the columns you were inserting to.

Try this instead;

```
INSERT INTO csat (`value`, `month`)
VALUES (1, '2017-06-15');

INSERT INTO migrated (`title`, `description`, `month`)
VALUES (2, 2, '2018-06-15');
```

Comment: Although I would use single quotation marks rather than double quotation marks. The SQL standard is single, and even MySQL uses single quotation marks in its [date/time reference page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html).

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Single is more standard.

Answer (score 3):

You have to wrap your date values in single quotation marks: `'2017-06-15'`, not `2017-06-15`. Right now, MySQL is evaluating this as `2017 minus 6 minus 15`, which comes to 1996.

Also, when inserting, it's best to specify the columns you're inserting into. And if your column is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`, you don't need to specify it:

```
INSERT INTO csat
(`value`, `month`)
VALUES 
(1, '2017-06-15');
```

I would also consider changing your column names. Perhaps make "value" more descriptive (value of what?) And `month` is misleading, since it's actually a date-type column.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you missed the single qoutes (as per Sql standards) at first in your date and then while inserting even if the column is autoincrement you need to specify columns other than the autoincrement column so as to make sure the data you are inserting belongs to that specific column or not
Try this

```
INSERT INTO 
  csat(value,month) values 
  (1,'2017-06-15')
```

Comment: Although I would use single quotation marks rather than double quotation marks. The SQL standard is single, and even MySQL uses single quotation marks in its [date/time reference page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html).

Comment: Yes, Its a standard to follow single quotes usage in sql and double qoutes be as to differentiate at times. I guess most of the database allows usage of both though

Comment: Actually, most other databases require a single quote, and interpret a double quote differently (you can test in SQL Server and Postgres, for example).

Comment: I have been using oracle though I was specific to that. I have edited in my answer as qoutes

Comment: Although both Oracle and MySQL have text like the following: "If the ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode is enabled, string literals can be quoted only within single quotation marks because a string quoted within double quotation marks is interpreted as an identifier." So I would argue that you're still better off sticking with the SQL standard.

Comment: Single qoutes are more standard. Agreed.